# Execute root Node Module with www-data user

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a video creator plugin called editly made in node. When i run the command on my ubuntu:

```
editly file.json
```

it creates the video normaly. But then i run the bash tha runs this code on browser (nginx server using www-data user) it doesnt run.

I think is about permission.

Can anyone help me out, please?

Thanks in advance